# Whats wrong in this code? Why it is printing "1"?

Tags: java

This is a Java code for printing the armstrong number from a user input a minimum digit to a user input maximum digit.

I'm getting no errors. The problem is that I the program prints an output of value 1.

How can I fix this?

```
package armstrong;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class armstrong {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter min number");
    int min=obj.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter max number");
    int max=obj.nextInt();
    int a;

    for (int j = min; j <=max; j++) 
     {

       int temp = j ;

        int l=digit(j);
        System.out.println(l);
        int sum=0;

        if(j>0)
        {
            a=j%10;

            sum=(int) (sum+Math.pow(a,l));
            j=j/10;

        }
        if(sum == temp)
            System.out.println(temp);
        //else
            //System.out.println(n+ " is not an armstrong number");

    }

}


//java.lang.Math.pow(double a, double b)
public static int digit(int x){

    int z=0;


    if(x<0)
    {
        x=x * -1;
    }
    else if(x==0)
    {
        x=1;
    }
    while(x>0)
    {
        x=x/10;
        z++;
    }
    return z;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your formatting is not quite correct. If you know how to use eclipse (or, gulp, jdb), then run it in debug mode. Otherwise, print the loop variable any time it is changed. Visually inspect the code to find the lvalue's.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are altering your for loop index variable, j, inside the loop. The `j = j/10` line automatically makes j go back to 0, and it can never increase when inside the loop, making your for loop stuck.

You should be altering the `temp` variable you created instead

this should work to not have your for loop be infinite:

```
for (int j = min; j <=max; j++) 
 {

   int temp = j ;

    int l=digit(j);
    System.out.println(l);
    int sum=0;

    if(j>0)
    {
        a=temp%10;

        sum=(int) (sum+Math.pow(a,l));
        temp=temp/10;

    }
    if(sum == j)
        System.out.println(j);
    //else
        //System.out.println(n+ " is not an armstrong number");

}
```

You still have a lot of work to do on your algorithm, however.

Take a look at this: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-armstrong-number